# How to get wp_ajax to work with jQuery $.post

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, wordpress, post

Straight from WP Codex: http://codex.wordpress.org/AJAX_in_Plugins

I have this in my functions.php:

```
add_action( 'admin_footer', 'my_action_javascript' );

function my_action_javascript() {
?>
<script type="text/javascript" >
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {

    var data = {
        'action': 'my_action',
        'whatever': 1234
    };

    // since 2.8 ajaxurl is always defined in the admin header and points to admin-ajax.php
    $.post(ajaxurl, data, function(response) {
        alert('Got this from the server: ' + response);
    });
});
</script>
<?php
}
add_action( 'wp_ajax_my_action', 'my_action_callback' );

function my_action_callback() {
    global $wpdb; // this is how you get access to the database

    $whatever = intval( $_POST['whatever'] );

    $whatever += 10;

        echo $whatever;

    die(); // this is required to return a proper result
}
```

And I don't get a response. I do get an alert saying 'Got this from the server: ', but no response. What gives?

Comment: Did you try to remove this? add_action( 'admin_footer', 'my_action_javascript' );

Comment: Not sure what you are trying to get at, but for s&g I removed it and yeah, the javascript doesn't fire at all (didn't work).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Running your code on two separate wordpress installs from within a plugin file (plugin-name.php) and from within functions.php in my theme, it returns the proper value both times. There do not seem to be any errors in your code either.

Is this the only javascript you're including in the admin area?

Comment: Thank you for this sanity check! I will check into the other javascript.

Comment: Found it. Thanks again TheJokersThief!